# UI annoyances in the suggested edit review on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, user-interface

On Stack Overflow, suggested edits need two reviewers. So when you're the first reviewer to give your opinion (approve or reject) or if you're the second but vote the other way than the first reviewer, the edit stays in the queue. This has two annoying consequences when you're going through the [suggested edit list](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) (5k only):

- If you cast the deciding vote, the entry for this edit disappears from the list (it's moved to a header line at the top of the list). Otherwise the edit remains in place. This is annoying because it means the position of the next entry on the screen depends on something that shouldn't be relevant (whether you just cast the deciding vote). It's especially annoying because the entry can take a couple of seconds to disappear when it does, which has led me to click on the wrong row a couple of times, when the next edit was an obvious accept or reject.
- If you revisit the list and one of the edits you voted on still hasn't been decided, the entry appears again (with no buttons). Why show me the entry again? There's nothing I can do about it any more.

Here's the behavior I'd like:

- An edit never disappears from the list as long as I don't reload the page.
- If I reload the page, edits I've already voted on don't appear.

Alternatively:

- When I've voted on an edit, it disappears to the collapsed list at the beginning, and stays there even if I reload the page.
- The disappearance should be instantaneous, with no fading.

Either way, please make the behavior on voting consistent whether my vote was the deciding one or not. And if the page is changed when I click on a vote button, the change should be instantaneous.

*But please don't let that deter you from reviewing a few suggested edits on Stack Overflow. [Visit the list](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits) and review one page (30 suggestions). We get 500–800 suggestions on a typical day. If 2% of the eligible ~5000 people do one page every day and vote on half the suggestions they see, we're good.*

Comment: Another annoyance: more than enough times I've been working off the list, gone off to one of the actual questions to see the edit in full context, spent a couple minutes there, and then come back to the list and start Approving/Rejecting edits that have already been taken care of by a couple different reviewers. This can be remedied by refreshing the page, but I forget to do that a lot. It also means I have to work back down through the refreshed list and ignore the ones I've already looked at and skipped.

Comment: In a way, you don't even need to see whether you'll be casting a deciding vote. If someone voted already, why do you need to know? If anything, seeing what someone else votes will only make your decision *less* objective because you might be partially swayed to go along with their vote and not put in as much effort as you would if someone hadn't already voted. So the system could be: You see a list of edits, you vote approve/decline and they stay in place. When you reload the page, anything you've voted on doesn't show up anymore. No reason to show other votes or do the fancy fade-out.

Comment: I would +1 this... but it seems I did when it was first posted ***last year***.. shame nothings been done about this.

Comment: **AND** make the "Improve" button from the queue open a new tab! Reviewing edits is already enough of a chore. Why do I have to fight the UI the whole time too?

Comment: This is pretty much all taken care of with the queue-based interface, albeit not in quite the way suggested.

Answer (score 16):

I was in the middle of writing my own question ranting about this. The three solutions I would accept were as follows;

1. **Never** remove a post from the list, as you loose your place in the queue. Instead, fade the post out so the user *knows* they've handled it. **Regardless of whether it's the deciding vote or not**.

   [image]
2. If the post is removed, scroll the user to a *consistent* place on the place; i.e. the next post that is to be removed.
3. Have [House of Pain - Jump Around](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vfblUSCaAQk) playing constantly in the background whilst in the suggested-edit queue.

   [image]

**EDIT:** In the meantime, I've written a [Userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/3436/suggested-edit-queue-v2-0)  which fixes these annoyances.

Comment: +1 for option #1. +100 for option #3.

Comment: +1 You actually wrote the Chrome extension? Wish you could write one for FF :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I looked at the option of porting it; it uses jQuery using jQuery inside a FF extension is a major headache.

Comment: @vcsjones: I am sure it is. And hence a bounty ;) Also the bounty is not for fading it but to remove it completely from my view on page refresh.

Comment: I cannot stop laughing at option #3.

Comment: Like Siddharth Rout, I'd prefer it if the items I've acted on were moved to the top, but the important thing is that the behavior is consistent. That, and not having edits I've already seen appear again when I reload the page. Thank you! (I'm not giving this an the check mark, I reserve it for the day — should it ever come — when this is a standard feature.)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Give the updated link (which is now an userscript) a go. Let me know if you come across any problems (I know edits fade at the moment... working on a removal option).

Comment: @Matt: Perfect. will wait for the "Removal" option.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: The new version adds a settings box to the bottom of the suggested edit queue. Change the "When an action is taken on an edit..." option to "Add to the top" and let me know how it goes! (if you can't see the settings box, try clearing your cache).

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I just tried the fade option. It fades even if I get the “out of votes” message. I would like to fade only if my vote was taken into account, not if I ran out of votes and also not if the edit was already rejected by the time I approved or vice versa.

Comment: @Gilles: I've just pushed a version which won't fade out on "out of votes"; give it 10 minutes for the Github CDN to clear and you should get it automatically. The same fix *might* also have caught the case of the edit being approved/ rejected before you got to it, but I need to see an example of the server response in that case to know what to check for... :(

Comment: @Matt “Out of votes” stays in place now, thanks. I can't test anything else until tomorrow.

Comment: @Gilles: Was thinking of [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2GRQ0.png) for a better UI for titles... [was this what you had in mind?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135710/please-show-changed-titles-separately-in-edit-diffs)

Comment: @Matt Yes, that would be great. Or perhaps [left and right as had been suggested before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112724/please-keep-title-edits-display-consistent-with-content-edits).

Comment: @Matt “This edit was already approved” stays in place. Yay! If you need a transcript for testing: http://pastebin.com/43uekwAD

Comment: @Matt Oh, but “This suggestion still needs 1 approval vote” also stays in place (“still needs 1 reject vote” and fully accepted/rejected do vanish). [Sample](http://pastebin.com/zdP86pBU)

Comment: @Gilles: Thanks! From what I could see, only "still needs 1 approval vote" wrongly stayed in place; the rest faded fine? (Fixed now... 10 mins for CDN to clear etc etc.)

Comment: @Matt: Which option do you want me to try?

Comment: @Matt: Do I need to use the userscript that you posted in the post or is it in one of the comments above?

Comment: @SiddharthRout: Urrr, I can't remember whether the auto-updater was included in the version you installed or not ;). Either way, you can install it again without any damage; [click here](https://github.com/downloads/mattlunn/se-edit-queue/se-edit-queue-install.user.js). Be sure to visit http://cloud.github.com/downloads/mattlunn/se-edit-queue/latest.js and hit CTRL + F5 before you go to the Suggested Edit page as well to ensure you're up-to-date.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, I am kind of noob here :) How do I install it?

Comment: @Matt Here, have a nice answer badge! That would solve my [one of my pet gripes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111703/disorientating-ui-when-dismissing-long-edit-suggestions) too. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is less of an answer and more of an additional gripe.

When choosing to 'Improve' a suggested edit, you're taken to the stand-alone edit page and on saving your edit, returned to the question page (not back to the Edit queue).

Can we not just edit in-place *à la* the other Review queues (Late Answers, etc.)?

**EDIT:** Now [posted as a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136868/can-we-improve-suggested-edits-in-place)

Comment: Widor, I think this justifies being it's own separately posted question. If this hasn't already been asked, consider asking it as a question... I have to keep reminding myself to use right-click -> open in new tab so that I don't lose my place on the edits page. It's very annoying indeed.

Comment: @jmort253 I'll have a search and do so if I can't find one then. Meanwhile, save yourself one second per edit by middle-clicking the link rather than selecting from the context menu!