# Disorientating UI when dismissing long edit suggestions

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, suggested-edits

**TL;DR version:** When a long edit suggestion is dismissed, subsequent entries take its place and reviewers loose their position in the list. Essentially, the current view jumps to an arbitrary point further down the page depending on length of the one dismissed.

---

At present, after casting the final accept/reject vote the entry fades away and is placed in a collapsed list at the top. I have no qualms about that behaviour in general.

However, it can get very disorientating when dealing with long entries that extend beyond the browser view. Subsequent entries take its place (above the visible page) and I end up not knowing where in the list I am. Backtracking to figure out which is the unreviewed entry is harder than it sounds.

Perhaps this mockup can illustrate the problem:

[image: View before and after an edit suggestion is dismissed]

**Suggestion:**

I propose that the page be scrolled to the next edit suggestion once the fadeout has completed. Ideally, this is only done if the dismissed entry extends beyond the current view.

I'm aware that some may be opposed to scripts force-scrolling the browser window, but surely its better than having the <strike>carpet</strike> page being pulled from under your feet.

*p.s. This post has some overlap with [in this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96426/134327), but deals with a different problem arrising from the behaviour and proposes a different solution.*

*p.p.s As mentioned in comments, this also happens in the other `/review` tabs e.g. when a vote-closed post is minimise. However, the collapsed entry is not moved away and so it serves as a marker which alleviates the confusion.*

Comment: The same thing happens with `/review/`

Comment: Clever solution. +1