# Please keep title edits display consistent with content edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, title, diff

Currently if the user edits the title of an answer as well as the content, the title changes are viewed in place (on the left) and the content changes are separate, on the right.

As a result you have to check the left hand side to see the change to the title, and the right hand side to see the content. I've nearly missed that there was a title change a couple of times.

I suggest that in the case where the title and content are both edited, either:

1. The title changes are shown consistent with content changes (new version on the right, old on the left). <-- my preferred option.
2. The changes to the title are shown above the old and new versions of the content.

Comment: +1 for the first option

Comment: I've made a userscript to do this. See my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256122/260841)