# Make suggested edit title changes easier to read

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, title, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please keep title edits display consistent with content edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112724/please-keep-title-edits-display-consistent-with-content-edits)
>   [Please show changed titles separately in edit diffs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135710/please-show-changed-titles-separately-in-edit-diffs)

While the red/green highlighting works great side-by-side, like in the body of a suggested edit, it's difficult to read in title changes because there is no before and after to compare.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/301235

> [image]
>   While this isn't the worst I've seen, it's still difficult to see how much better the new title is compared to the old. In body changes, the side-by-side display makes this easy.

I suggest separating the current and suggested titles. Here are a few ideas in order of preference:

**#1** - Side-by-side just like the body

> [image]

**#2** - Stacked

> [image]

**#3** - Stacked, alternate color scheme (entire title red or green, no need for caption)

> [image]

Not related, but similar title (I did look): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78046/172756

Comment: I suck at searching. I seriously look for this and found nothing. I guess I was focused on the "suggested edit" part of it.

Comment: I've made a userscript. See my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256122/260841)